# What we have been up to (Bi-Monthly report from the Strike Team)

Tags: discussion

A while ago we introduced [GD.SE's Strike Force](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/577/introducing-the-gd-se-strike-force). Since then, we've been planning and implementing some very humble ideas. I think it's time we report, because **it's good news!**

**The Chat is aliiiiive!**

One of our main goals was to bring our chat room back to life, after a long (looong) time frozen. We are back! And we have cats!

Some things we did were:

- We first prepared the [Chat guidelines](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/what-are-the-rules-for-chat/598#598), or rules of etiquette for our fancy room,
- We added Chat feeds (We have a great selection of GD blogs! [Check them out](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/622/graphic-design-blogs-for-our-chat-ticker))
- We [renamed the room](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231/renaming-the-chatroom-done), made the description more inviting. This worked out really well, because we now have people coming from other rooms (mainly because of the cats).

**Survival and Adaptation**

We successfully migrated to SE's new Close system and the Help Center!

- [Off-topic reasons](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/606/what-are-our-custom-off-topic-reasons) for the new closing system
- [Help Center](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/603/new-help-center-is-live)

**Improvements to the Site**

Like geniuses driven by... nevermind.

We cleaned.

- Completed and formatted most of the wiki tags excerpts
- Cleaned tags and created a bunch of synonyms
- Took care of a lot of flags (our average handling time is less than 3 hours, a record!)
- Censored and re-worded badge-awarding amounts of questions, answers and comments

**In planning**

Some of these are coming very soon! We keep a [**Trello board with our ideas**](https://trello.com/b/lfygcxyQ/gd-se-strike-team) (it's public to see, just send us a message for an invite to edit), so **please join us!**

- "Celebrity" chat-cast (soon!)
- [Logo of the Week Contest](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/581/logo-of-the-week-contest)
- We would like to try scheduled events, like "Bounty Day" or "Ask about ... Day". What do you think?
- We were toying with the idea of a [GD.SE Blog](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/549/would-you-like-to-have-participate-in-a-gd-se-blog)

We have more visits, more questions and more answers than ever. We are growing, and we have a great community. Not too bad for a beta!

*Your loving Pro-Tem Mods*,

**JohnB** & **Yisela**

Answer (score 1):

So glad you've been doing all this. As buried in work projects as I've been, it's been hard (okay, impossible) to log in as often as I would like. Awesome what you've accomplished! :-)

Comment: Thanks Alan! It's great to see you back. You have probably seen [this post](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/637/why-is-graphic-design-still-beta), right? It's happening!

Comment: Yep. Jin ran a design by me many months ago that I commented at the time seemed rather bland. Looking forward to seeing what he comes up with!

Comment: Poor Jin - having to come up with a design that a community of designers agree on! Not sure I'd accept that brief...

Comment: No kidding! :) That's got to be one of the hardest briefs ever.